# How do I interact with a child process pretending to be a terminal?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to interact with an NCURSES program.

As an example I'm using GNU Screen and run aptitude inside. (you could try it with mc instead.)

The program below starts a screen session with -x to connect to my session.

I want to navigate by pressing Arrow-down and Arrow-up.

If I send 'q' for quit I see a box pop up in my other screen session.

What do I need to do to get special keys like arrow keys working?

It currently seems to ignore the VT102 sequence I'm sending.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        reactor.callLater(1.0, self.foo)

    def foo(self):
        self.transport.write('\033[B')

    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited, status %s" % (reason.value.exitCode,)

    def outReceived(self, data):
        print data

    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "errReceived!", data

pp = MyPP()
command = ['screen', '-x']
reactor.spawnProcess(pp, command[0], command, {'TERM':'xterm'}, usePTY=True)

reactor.run()
```

**UPDATE**:

1. Ted told me walking in the command history with ESC [ A (up) and ESC [ B (down) works with bash.
2. Wondering why in aptitude it doesn't I've changed TERM=xterm to TERM=ansi which fixes it. Why xterm doesn't work still puzzles me.

Comment: This is a somewhat confusing question - are you asking how to send control keys, such as Arrow-down, across the network over Twisted?

Comment: Not across network. spawnProcess starts a process locally and wires up file descriptors so you can talk to it.

Comment: Is the ESC B in `foo` meant to be the down-arrow?  Down-arrow generates ESC [ B, not just ESC B.

Comment: @torek I updated it to ESC[B. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a program that uses just readline?

Comment: @yaccz bash uses readline. I just found out that actually works. I still have a problem with TERM=xterm. (see update)

Comment: That is pretty obvious, but have you diffed the terminfo for ansi and xterm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've changed TERM=xterm to TERM=ansi which fixes it. Why xterm doesn't
>   work still puzzles me.

Using Ubuntu 13.04, it looks like the `ansi` and `xterm` control codes aren't quite the same.

```
$ infocmp ansi | grep cud
        cr=^M, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\E[D, cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\E[B,
        kcud1=\E[B, kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A, khome=\E[H, kich1=\E[L,

$ infocmp xterm | grep cud
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
```

...so it looks like you need to send the string `'\033OB'` to emulate a down arrow with `xterm`.

The following code works for me...

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

# Set TERM=xterm in case it isn't already
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm'

# Spawn aptitude
p = subprocess.Popen('aptitude', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Wait for a bit to let it load from cache
time.sleep(5)

# Control it using xterm control codes
p.stdin.write('\033OB') # arrow down
time.sleep(1)
p.stdin.write('\033OB') # arrow down
time.sleep(1)
p.stdin.write('\033OA') # arrow up
time.sleep(1)
p.stdin.write('\033OA') # arrow up
time.sleep(1)
p.stdin.write('q')      # quit
time.sleep(1)
p.stdin.write('y')      # confirm
```

...although it screwed up my terminal after completion, so I had to do...

```
$ stty sane
```

...to get it working again.

---

**Update**

Just found what might be an easier way to determine the correct control codes. If you load `vi`, go into insert mode, then press `CTRL-V` followed by the key you want to emulate, it shows the literal string sent from the terminal.

For example...

```
Down Arrow: ^[OB

Page Up: ^[[5~
```

...where `^[` is `CTRL-[`, i.e. `'\033'`.

Answer (score 2):

A good method to obtain codes for particular terminal functions is using the `tput` command, for some particular terminal type with `-T` option.

In Python, use the `curses` module to obtain correct codes:

```
from curses import *
setupterm('xterm')

key_up = tigetstr("kcuul")
key_down = tigetstr("kcudl")
```

You can read about available capabilities by launching `man terminfo`. The example above may need `savetty()` before `setupterm` and `resetty()` after you obtain the key codes you are interested in. Otherwise, your terminal may be left in a *bad* state. In C it was good to have that in some exit handler as well, to reset terminal on error, but the Python module may handle that in its own.

This method, in contrast to hardcoding the terminal codes, has the advantage of being portable between systems, where *terminfo* for *xterm* may be different than that on current Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like Pexpect might by useful here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect

Its a python implementation of Expect, which basically watches input and based on patterns performs actions as if a person was sitting there interacting with the app.

Comment: I should have a closer look at pexpect. I'm interested in monitoring patterns in the vt102 codes. I'm now writing my own pattern matching, but I'd be interested to see if I can use pexpect somehow.